# Is it possible to send a custom parameter to FB getloginurl()?

Tags: php, facebook, api

Something like this, so that custom_param might be used upon redirect back to the app:

```
$params = array(
'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_photos,status_update',
'redirect_uri' => base_url(),
'custom_param' => 'bazinga',
);
        
// LOGGED OUT       
$auth_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

A simple yay or nay would be great if you have experience in this.

Comment: Can’t you just put that value as an additional parameter into your redirect_uri?

Comment: Hi - no, if I do that, the login fails - FB is failing to add to the $_SESSION array unless the redirect_uri is exactly the one specified in the app (for webite) settings.. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It's not really meant for this, but there is a `state` parameter you can pass that gets returned to you. [See the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)

Comment: If you’re using state for transferring a simple parameter, it’ll lose it’s meaning as a way to detect CSRF. So if you need to transfer let’s say the value _foo_ then I’d at least make the state something like foo_{something_still_random}

Comment: I'm finding that if I send a custom 'state' parameter through, that's NOT generated automatically by the API, the process fails to append the required data to the $_SESSION array, so this doesn't work for me. Quite frustrating, as this all stems from my needing to enable a relatively frictionless login/redirect process from a page that's not the app's BASE_URL. Thanks for your input though. Any other ideas?

Comment: PS - it looks like in the PHP API, the process does a check - the $_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_state'] vs. the $_GET['state'] that is returned in the URL. I'm sending through a custom state, so it's mismatching against the session, and not appending the login details to the $_SESSION array.

Comment: _“I'm sending through a custom state, so it's mismatching against the session”_ – well, can’t you just override $_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_state'] with your own state then, just before making the login URL redirect …? (Sorry, I haven’t tried something like this yet, so I’m just spitballing here …)